# Creating NSDate from NSString.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, null, nsdateformatter

I have stored a date in a text file, and I can read it out properly. The output for this string is

"6:00 PM"

Just like that. However, when I do:

```
//First, set the first datePicker
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

     NSString *breakfastTimeStartLocation = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"breakfastTimeStart.txt"];

    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:breakfastTimeStartLocation encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Loaded time is %@", time);
    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];

    NSLog(@"Start Date = %@", startDate);
```

In this, `time` returns the `"6:00 PM"`, but `startDate` returns `"(null)"`

I must be missing something, why in the world does this not work?

Thanks.

Comment: Also note that if I just trying setting the datePicker to `startDate`, it throws an exception.

Comment: Did you try setting a date format for your dateFormatter?     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

Comment: -1 for blaming your tools.

Comment: @HotLicks, For blaming my tools? What does that mean?

Comment: Saying dateFromString was not working properly, when you were not using it properly.

Comment: @HotLicks, Oh yes. You are right, when I wrote the question it seemed to not be working, since I thought I added the code that was provided by the answer below. But you are right, I will edit the question. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That's not the right way to init an `NSDateFormatter`, the designated initializer is `initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:`

Thus:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]
initWithDateFormat:@"h:mm a" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
```

Comment: It is the proper way. This is not even available on Cocoa Touch. :)

Comment: It's gotta get a format, though... use `setTimeFormat:` and `setDateFormat:`

Comment: That's not correct. Use `init` unless you need the pre OS X Tiger behaviors, per NSDateFormatter documentation.

Comment: @iluvcapra ... *slaps face*, Well, I thought for sure I added those lines. Turns out I accidentally added them in the wrong method. I really need to start labeling thing better. Well, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you never set a Date Format. Even if this is not the only problem it would probably be one. Try something like:

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
```